# Metric condition that implies Triangle Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that $\forall x,y,z \in X, d(x,z) \leq max \{ d(x,y), d(y,z) \} $ implies Triangle Inequality(M4), where $d: X \times X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$

For (M4): $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$  which is the Triangle inequality for metric spaces

Comment: What did you try to do? What are your thoughts about this question?

Comment: What is M4??? You need to make some vague attempt. Just writing down the condition for the triangle inequality and looking at the above should give some idea of what to do.

Comment: I have made some changes

Comment: To prove it you use [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Basic_definitions) of $\leq$. Since $d(x,z)\leq\max(d(x,y),d(y,z))$ and since $\max(d(x,y),d(y,z))\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, then $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

One fact, if $a,b\ge 0$ in the reals

$$\max(a,b) \le a+b$$

Proof: if $a \le b$, $\max(a,b)=b \le a+b$ as $a \ge 0$ and if $b \le a$, $\max(a,b)=a \le a+b$ as $b \ge 0$. And $a \le b$ or $b \le a$ holds (linear order).